# NServiceBus Use 4.0 Handler in 2.6 saga

Tags: nservicebus, saga, nservicebus4

we have a saga that calls numerous handlers.  I want to start the migration from 2.6 to 4.0 so I have upgraded one of the handlers to 4.0.  If I deploy this handler alongside the other 2.6 handlers and with a 2.6 saga that calls both types of handlers is there going to be trouble?  Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the  [NServiceBus 4.0 release notes](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/releases/tag/4.0.0)

it states that 4.x is not compatible with 2.x...

upgrading to 3.x and then 4.x seems like a less painful option

Comment: Well, it just seems that if a 2.6 saga sends a message to the queue and 4.0 handler picks it up, processes it then sends a message to the queue and the 2.6 saga picks it up, there would be no interaction and thus it should work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You may want to test it, i guess a 4.x handler can consume a 2.x message, but of the top of my head, a 2.x endpoint will be looking for a message implementing IMessage for example?... Message headers are not compatible, and i'm sure there is more

Comment: Ah. Message headers. I don't really know much about bus systems.  Just that ours needs a serious enema and step one is to upgrade to the latest.  I kind of figured a message was just a chunk of generic xml, but now that I think about it of course it's specific at least to nservicebus and probably to the version to some extent.  Thanks for the help